# Grails addTo* clarification

Tags: grails, grails-orm, flush

I am following the example in Grails in Action. I have an issue understanding how the `addTo*()` function works.

I have a simple domain: User, Post, Tag with the following relationships:

- User 1-to-M Post
- User 1-to-M Tag
- Post M-to-M Tag

When I run the following code (first case):

```
1.  def user = new User(userId: 'joe', password: 'secret').save()
2.  def tagGroovy = new Tag(name: 'groovy')
3.  def tagGrails = new Tag(name: 'grails')
4.  user.addToTags(tagGroovy)              
5.  user.addToTags(tagGrails)            
6.  
7.  def groovyPost = new Post(content: 'A groovy post')
8.  user.addToPosts(groovyPost)          
9.  groovyPost.addToTags(tagGroovy)
10.         
11. User.get(1).tags.each {println it.id + " " + it.name}
12. User.get(1).posts.each {println it.id + " " + it.content + " " + it.dateCreated}
```

I get this:

```
null grails
null groovy
null A groovy post null
```

And if I change lines 4, 5, and 8 to:

```
4.  user.addToTags(tagGroovy).save(flush: true)              
5.  user.addToTags(tagGrails).save(flush: true)    
8.  user.addToPosts(groovyPost).save(flush: true)
```

I get this:

```
2 grails
1 groovy
1 A groovy post Tue Nov 22 21:00:00 WET 2011
```

Can someone explain why in the first case the `id` and `dateCreated` properties are not persisted?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's really a hibernate issue.

The entire object graph gets saved only when you save your user object. So they are associated with the user but not yet persisted in the database, so they have no ids.

In your example, if you add User.save( flush: true ) before your get(1) lines, you will see that all the new posts get persisted in the database.

Peter Ledbrook explains it a little better in this post - http://blog.springsource.org/2010/06/23/gorm-gotchas-part-1/